# Does Maxwell stress tensor take into account dielectrophoretic and electrophoretic forces?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, maxwell-equations, simulations

I'm a mechanical engineer (this question might be very fundamental), and I am working on simulating the behavior of a particle in water when subjected to an electric field. In my simulation, I am using Maxwell Stress Tensor (MST) to calculate the electric stress and apply it as a volume force to the particle and water (coupled using COMSOL).
My question is: What are the forces that MST takes into account? Does it take into account other forces such as Electrophoretic (on charged) and Dielectrophoretic, which depend on the electric field too, or is it just the electric force due on charged bodies that it calculates?